# display message box only once

Tags: c#-4.0, batterylevel

I am using the following code to display a message box when the charging level is reached

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        battery = Convert.ToInt32(power.BatteryLifePercent * 100);

        while (battery == 100)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("charging full disconnect the charger");
        }
    }
```

this code is working . but it is showing messagebox more than once.
I just want to show it only once.

Thank you

Comment: Where is your code being called from to make it run more than once?

Comment: The code you have shown isnt causing the repetition. Show the what's calling this code

Comment: it is called using a timer for every 1 sec

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it is hard to determine the actual problem. However, you can probably quickly fix the issue by using a variable to track whether you have displayed the message yet.

```
PowerStatus power = SystemInformation.PowerStatus;

int battery = 0;
bool battery_message_shown = false;

if( battery == 100 && battery_message_shown == false )
{
  battery_message_shown = true;
  MessageBox.Show("charging full");
}
```

Although, ideally, this code simply wouldn't be called unless it is time to show the message. I would need to see the larger picture to figure that out though.

Comment: I am getting this error
The event 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.Shown' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Comment: shown must be used elsewhere, my bad, updating answer to use battery_message_shown instead

Answer (score 0):

The condition associated with your while loop will never be reached the way it is coded. That is why the body of the loop will keep getting executed.

You need to embed code that changes or refreshes the condition. However, if you do this the program will draw much resources since the battery charging process is generally time consuming. What you would then need to do is probable do a thread.sleep for some duration or better yet use a timer.

This code example is doing something similar and is probably worth review in your case:
[BlackWasp-PowerStatusCheck](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/PowerStatus.aspx).